# Android Fragment not displayed on one device

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

One of my activities has 3 fragments that are supposed to layout one after the other top to bottom. Works perfectly on my Sony Xperia Z3C (Android 6.0.1) phone, but on my Samsung J1 mini (android 5.1.1).  The 3rd/bottom fragment is not shown at all.

There is an empty space where it could go and I know that the empty space is empty - I set a background on fragments 2 and 3, and 2 changed but there was still an empty space under it.

I tweaked the code and put a second copy of fragment 2 in and that worked, so I'm assuming it is a problem in the Fragment itself.

I know the Fragment is created (it's onCreateView is called and the Activity can find it using the FragmentManager) but it just won't show up on one of my phones.

Any hints greatly appreciated.

This is the fragment (names changed but nothing else...)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.FragC">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="4"
        tools:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnX"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="scoreButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/xLab" />

        <!-- more buttons just the text, column and row changes -->


    </GridLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And this is the activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activityLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.Activity1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragA"
        android:name="com.example.FragA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_frag_a" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragB"
        android:name="com.example.FragB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragb" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragC"
        android:name="com.example.FragC"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragmen_fragc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I just remembered that I have a landscape version of this activity. It's top level is a horizontal linear layout. Left column is a vertical linear layout containing fragment 1 and 2, then fragment 3 (aka the invisible fragment) should appear to the right. It doesn't. Space is there for it, but no fragment.

**Update** I took all the buttons out of the fragment and replaced them with a TextView (all default values via the GUI) and that showed up. It would appear something in the buttons is confusing the Samsung...

I changed the button width from 0dp to wrap_content and now I see the first column of buttons. I can see the 2nd and 3rd col, but if I try to add the 4th col the all I can see is the 1st. Something really odd with the layout...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I have my answer: Throw away the GridLayout and use nested LinearLayouts instead.

As I said the original code worked on 1 device but not another.

Changing the width helped. Setting a fixed width let me get all of the buttons, but using wrap_content when the last button was added, only button 1 was left.

I could not figure out what the problem was and most answers I found said use nested LinearLayouts. I did and they worked!.